# How to Show the progressbar like incremental status updates for long requests

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have to send the longtime request to server in my Asp.net application, that request i called 4 services, each service take max of 1min , so i want to show prograssbar which service is completed , i searched one link [Example](http://encosia.com/easy-incremental-status-updates-for-long-requests/), it is correct about my concept but that link using iframe to load another page that page write method like

```
protected void UpdateProgress(int PercentComplete, string Message)
{
  // Write out the parent script callback.
  Response.Write(String.Format(
    "<script>parent.UpdateProgress({0}, '{1}');</script>", 
    PercentComplete, Message));
  // To be sure the response isn't buffered on the server.
  Response.Flush();
}
```

In this code to call javascript function in parent aspx page to update details , but i have in same page to handle that concept , **i removed "Parent." in my code get the error object expected** how to write the code in single page

Answer (score 0):

With help of jQuery (http://jQuery.com) you could do the following in javascript:

```
function callServices() {
   var serviceUrls = ["http://yourdomain/svc1", "http://yourdomain/svc2", "http://yourdomain/svc3", "http://yourdomain/svc4"];
   for(i = 0; i < serviceUrls.length; i++) {
      $.ajax(serviceUrls[i], function(){ updateStatus("Service " + i); });
   }
}

function updateStatus(svc) {
    $("#statusBar").append("<span>" + svc + " has finished.</span>");
}
```

Cheers!